# Cannot resolve symbol issue with LocalTime methods java

Tags: javafx, localtime

I am trying to just fill a combo box with some LocalTime objects. For some reason if I try to use the start object I created none of the methods are recognized. So its saying cannot resolve symbol for the isBefore method and plusSeconds method shown below. Any idea why this is happening. I have imported the LocalTime class and I have no issues with declaring the LocalTime objects start and end.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(6,0);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(8,0);

while(start.isBefore(end.plusSeconds(1))){
    startTimeComboBox.getItems().add(start);
    start = start.plusMinutes(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the isBefore and plusSeconds methods are an instance methods and only seems to work when inside of my initialize method. Not sure why I had them outside of that method to begin with.